# Detect when a fifo is opened from a program

Tags: c, unix, race-condition, fifo

I have a situation where I need to check if the other side of a fifo has opened it, however I can't use a open because otherwise the program will start doing stuff.

Why I have to do this: I have a program (a monitor) that launches a server program (both created by me). The monitor uses this fifo to communicate beacause the monitor can be closed/reopened while the server is already started.

The problem is when the monitor starts the server: in this case I have to wait in some way for fifos to be created and then open them.
Actually I'm using a while on the monitor that checks when the fifos are created, however in this way it opens the fifos **before** the server could do it (even if the instruction after the mkfifo is actually the open!!!).

You may say that I'm opening the fifos in wrong order on the monitor (I'm opening the Write fifo(WRONLY) before the read fifo), the problem is that I can't revert this order because it's required that the server will wait for clients on the open (RDONLY) fifo.

Any suggestion on how to avoid this race condition?
I'm actually using a sleep in the monitor after checking if fifos are created, this obviusly solves the problem but I think is definitely not correct.

Thanks to everyone

**Edit 1:**

This is how things are working at the moment

**Server**

```
mkfifo(fifo1)
mkfifo(fifo2)
open(fifo1 O_RDONLY)
open(fifo2 O_WRONLY)
```

**Monitor**

```
while (fifo1 doesn't exists && fifo2 doesn't exists);
open(fifo1 O_WRONLY)
open(fifo2 O_RDONLY)
```

I think the race condition is quite explicit now, it's important to notice that fifos are blocking (only RDONLY are blocking, WRONLY will not block even if there isn't anyone on the other side => **this is a unix behaviour, not designed by me**).

**Edit 2:**

The race condition happens at first fifo open level. **I must open the first fifo on the server before the monitor does it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least what I found 'till now makes me understand that **there isn't a way to detect if a fifo is opened**, except if you open it too.

**Edit 1:**

As Jason stated, there are two ways (both not allowed in my homework however):

1) *You could do a search through /proc/*PID*/fd (replace PID with a numerical process ID) to see what client processes had already opened your FIFO*
2) *Another option would be to call fuser on your FIFO*

However, the first one requires something that teachers don't want: watching inside proc/PID/fd. The second one I heared requires root privileges, and this is again something I can't do. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Technically, if you wanted to know if a FIFO was opened by another process, and you did not want to attempt an open on the file itself to avoid blocking, you could do a search through /proc/*PID*/fd (replace *PID* with a numerical process ID) to see what client processes had already opened your FIFO ... the values inside of /proc/*PID*/fd are symbolic links to opened files by that process.  Your search-time could be cut-down further if you knew what the client PID values are, otherwise you can simply do a brute-force search through all the running processes.

Comment: Another option would be to call `fuser` on your FIFO ... you can use `popen()` to open a pipe to a child-process that will run that command and then return the results.

Comment: Mh it's interesting and maybe they are the correct answers. However, teacher explicitly said not to use /proc/PID/fd (well you couldn't know this, but the question is not focused on the homework). As for fuser, I heared it requires root privileges (so I can't use it). Is it true?

Comment: There's no issues in using `fuser` itself as non-root ... the main issues in using `fuser` without root-privledges are that processes not owned by the current user may not show-up in the response from `fuser`.

Comment: Mh this could be a problem because I don't know who run server

Comment: You should be running the server since your monitor started the server ... therefore the server and monitor processes are ones that you have started, and you own.

Comment: Yes but for some reason they could have started it as root and after restart the monitor as a normal user (the server doesn't get necessarily if the monitor get closed).

Answer (score 2):

If you do the open()s in the right order, there is no race condition. (the only possible race would be a third process interfering with the same fifos)  From the fine manual :

"However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it.  Opening a FIFO for reading normally  blocks  until some other process opens the same FIFO
for writing, and vice versa."

This means that the ordering

{ process 1: open (fifo1, RO); process2: open (fifo1, WO); }

...

{ process 1: open (fifo2, WO); process2: open (fifo2, RO); }

will always succeed (given no process starvation) The order of operations on each fifo is unimportant; for fifo1 either process1 or process2 can go first (and will be blocked until the other side succeeds).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FIFO1 "fifo1"
#define FIFO2 "fifo2"

void do_master(void);
void do_slave(void);
void randsleep(unsigned max);

/************************************/
void do_master(void)
{
int in,out, rc;
char buff[20];

randsleep(5);
mkfifo(FIFO1, 0644);
randsleep(7);
mkfifo(FIFO2, 0644);

out = open(FIFO2, O_WRONLY);
if (out == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[Master]: failed opening output\n" );
    return;
    }
fprintf(stderr, "[Master]: opened output\n" );
in = open(FIFO1, O_RDONLY);
if (in == -1)  {
    fprintf(stderr, "[Master]: failed opening input\n" );
    close(out);
    return;
    }
fprintf(stderr, "[Master]: opened input\n" );

rc = write( out, "M2S\n\0" , 5);
fprintf(stderr, "[Master]: wrote %d\n", rc );

rc = read( in, buff , sizeof buff);
fprintf(stderr, "[Master]: read %d: %s\n", rc, buff );
unlink(FIFO1);
unlink(FIFO2);
}
/***********************************/
void do_slave(void)
{
int in,out, rc;
unsigned iter=0;
char buff[20];

loop1:
in = open(FIFO2, O_RDONLY);
if (in == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[Slave%u]: failed opening input\n", ++iter );
    randsleep(2);
    goto loop1;
    }
fprintf(stderr, "[Slave]: opened input\n" );

loop2:
out = open(FIFO1, O_WRONLY);
if (out == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[Slave%u]: failed opening output\n", ++iter );
    randsleep(3);
    goto loop2;
    }
fprintf(stderr, "[Slave]: opened output\n" );

rc = write( out, "S2M\n\0" , 5);
fprintf(stderr, "[Slave]: wrote %d\n", rc );

rc = read( in, buff , sizeof buff);
fprintf(stderr, "[Slave]: read %d:%s\n", rc, buff );
}
/*************************************/
void randsleep(unsigned max)
{
unsigned val;
val = rand();
val %= max;
sleep(val);
return;
}
/*************************************/
int main(void)
{
int rc;

switch (rc=fork()) {
    case -1: exit(1); break;
    case 0: do_slave(); break;
    default: do_master(); break;
    }
exit (0);
}
```

Comment: I see but I don't understand why I had a problem with race condition so (I had the problem that fifo was early opened in writeonly mode before it was opened as readonly)

Comment: Well, we don't know either, until you show us some real code. Opening on either end of a pipe _should_ block until the other end is opened. Adding checks involving /proc/, readdir(), stat(), etc,  only opens a window for other races. Open() is atomic; two open()s at either side are a synchronisation primitive. (or one of them blocks eternally)

Comment: I can't show code, it's a "big" projects (well has at least 20 files), otherwise I would have done it.

Comment: Well you could have stripped it down to a minimal example that demonstrates your issue. Since there is no intervening code (see my answer) this should be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a named semaphore using `sem_open()` that is visible to each program at the file-system level in order to synchronize the two programs.  Basically your monitor program will wait on the locked semaphore until the server increases it.  At that point, all the fifo's will be initialized, and you can move foward with your monitor with the fifo's in a known-state.

Make sure to use the `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` flags on the initial call to `sem_open()` so that the creation of the semaphore is atomic.  For example, both the monitor and the server program will attempt to create the semaphore at startup if it doesn't already exist ... if it exists, the call will fail, meaning the either the monitor or the server, but not both programs, gained the right to create the semaphore and initialize it.  The monitor then waits on the semaphore while the server initializes the fifo's ... once the fifo's are initialized, the server releases the semaphore, and the monitor is then able to continue.

Here's the process as I'm envisioning it ... I believe it should effectively solve your race condition:

In the monitor:

1. Create the named semaphore and set it in a locked state
2. Launch the server
3. Wait for the FIFO's to be visible at the file-system level
4. Open `fifo1` for writing (non-blocking)
5. Open `fifo2` for reading (blocks until the server opens `fifo2` for writing)
6. Wait on the semaphore (possibly with a timeout) until the server unlocks it, indicating that it has now opened both FIFO's successfully.

In the server:

1. Create the FIFO's
2. Open `fifo1` (blocks until the monitor opens it for writing)
3. Open `fifo2` (non-blocking)
4. Unlock the semaphore now that the server has opened both FIFO's

So basically your monitor cannot continue until there is a "known-state" where everything is properly initialized ... the server indicates that state to the monitor via the named semaphore.

Comment: Well, I think there is a problem: if I unlock the semaphore on the server just before opening the fifo, the monitor will still "win" the race to open the fifo first. And I can't unlock the semaphore after the open because it's a blocking open :\

Comment: On a fifo when it's opening as RDONLY is a blocking call, you can even see it on a process screen they have WCHAN = pipe_wait

Comment: The named semaphore can be used *after* the calls to `open()` to let you know that the server is ready to-do a `read()` on it's opened FIFO.  In other words your monitor can't do a write on the FIFO until the semaphore is released ... basically readers unlock the semaphore, allowing writers to write to the FIFO.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem, I must open (on the server) the first fifo, before the monitor does it. There isn't any problem after both opened the fifos.

Comment: That's impossible... A read-only call to open a FIFO will block until there is at least one writer that has opened the FIFO.

Comment: Quick question ... why is this specific ordering necessary? ... is there something else happening (i.e., something else needs to write to the FIFO first) such that the monitor cannot be the first program to open the write-only FIFO?

Comment: Yes, the monitor isn't the only "client". After the monitor has started the server, it can be closed and some clients can work on the server. So it's important that the server stays "blocked" on the first open.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL : That reason doesn't really explain why you need to stay blocked on the first open ... if there are no writers on the FIFO, then you'll simply read 0-bytes, and/or you could use `poll` or `select` to check when data is available to read from the FIFO.

Comment: The requirement (for the homework) is that the server will stay blocked on first open, so it must be done in this way. Also polling is not a good idea because will waste cpu cycles

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL : Manual busy-waiting wastes CPU cycles ... `poll` and `select` put the process to sleep and wake it up when there is something ready for reading.  Secondly, you mention the server must stay blocked, but it will unblock when anyone else opens the FIFO for writing, including a client ... so when is the server allowed to unblock from `open()`?

Comment: The server stays blocked on the first open, when someone does a open on the first fifo, the server unlocks, do stuff for that client and then it blocks again (this is requested by teacher). I think I didn't understand what you asked, hopefully this is the answer

Comment: Thanks for that info ... my next question is what is the monitor program suppose to be doing while the server is blocked on the FIFO waiting for clients?

Comment: Well the monitor program can send some commands (like a client can do), that are different from clients. For example a client can send/receive some messages (it's a program simulating a mailbox). The monitor can add a new user (or remove one) or resize a mailbox. The monitor is supposed to wait for user input (commands) to send to the server. Monitor uses same fifos as client. Only 1 client (the monitor can be considered a client) per time can access the fifos while doing it's request.

Comment: Writes to FIFO's are atomic... There is no harm in having multiple writers open on the same FIFO.

Comment: Not completely true, writes on fifos are atomic 'till bytes written are lesser than or equal to PIPE_BUF. By the way I solved the problem by allowing a the server and client program to "reverse" the order they open the fifos only when started (and only one time). Didn't find any other way. (I don't think this is something clean by the way)

Comment: Yes, I knew about the size of PIPE_BUF being a condition on atomic writes to a FIFO, but I didn't think you were trying to write more than 512-bytes per message, therefore I didn't feel a need to mention it ... BTW, I'm a little puzzled by your solution, simply because the server won't stay blocked on `open()` like you were asking -- the monitor will open `fifo1` for writing after it opens `fifo2` for reading, unblocking the server.  You'll still need to add a semaphore or some IPC synchronization object in order to block the monitor from opening `fifo1` until the server says it can be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Unix domain sockets of type `SOCK_STREAM`. The server will `bind` its socket to a name in the filesystem. Each client gets its own bidirectional connection to the server.